# ACF - don't show passed events and filter with start date

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a list of events and I'd like to do 2 things :

- order posts according to starting date
- don't include passed events in the query

I did some research and builded a query but it doesn't work.

'''

```
        $current_date = date_i18n('d.m.y');
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'spectacles',
            'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                  'key'     => 'header_spec_period_start',
                  'type' => 'DATE'
                  ),
              array(
                  'key'     => 'header_spec_period_end',
                  'value'       => '$current_date',
                  'compare' => '>',
                  'type' => 'DATE'
              ),
          ),
            'order' => 'ASC' ) );
        ?>
```

'''

All the events are showing, I can't get the passed events filtered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_now = date('Ymd');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'spectacles',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'header_spec_period_start',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'header_spec_period_start',
                    'compare' => '>',
                    'value' => $date_now,
                ),
            ),

        );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can try this ...

Comment: Thanks but it has the same results. Is it normal I don't see the header_spec_period_end in your example ? Because this is what I'd like to use to check if the date is passed.

Comment: Also, I was wondering if there was something wrong with the date format. In my ACF configuration I use d/m/Y in admin and d.m.y in template.

Comment: to order posts according to starting date you can  try `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`  check my edits in above answer, and since you don't want to include past date post, there is no need of  **header_spec_period_end**

Comment: Not really, sometimes events are going for 1 month, sometimes it's one day. That's why I want to use the end date.

Comment: set today's date as `$date_now = date('Ymd');`

Comment: It works ! But I still don't understand why the end date isn't used. Can you explain it to me please ? I'd like to know :-)

Comment: If it works then you can accept answer ... talking about "end date" : - Because we are not concerned about when Event will end.  We only want future date events, so there is no need of "end date"

Comment: I changed the starting date of a show to the date of yesterday but the end date is in july => the event disappeared while it should have stayed visible because it's still going on util to july. This is why i'm trying to compare the ending date.

Comment: then change `header_spec_period_start` to `header_spec_period_end` in above answer

Comment: Ok and if I want to also order the posts by start date ? Can I do it like this : 'orderby' => 'header_spec_period_start', ?

Comment: NO, `orderby` should be `meta_value_num`, or `meta_value`, not the name of the key.

Comment: Oh ok. How can I combine the two? Ordering by starting date and not showing the events that ended ?